# discord py reaction detection not working

Tags: discord.py

def checkReaction(reaction, user):
user != bot.user and (str(reaction.emoji) == ':x:' or str(reaction.emoji) == '✂' or str(reaction.emoji) == ':snake:')

```
reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=checkReaction) #This line gets run but                    after this line nothing gets run

if str(reaction.emoji) == ':x:':
    #Call Tic Tac Toe
    print('test')
    await ttt(ctx, bot)
```

im making a discord game bot this bit is for detecting the reactions, but its not working

Comment: Can you show us your entire file through Pastebin?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/stfiETiQ this file gets run from a different file

Comment: Please include relevant code (like the `checkReaction` function) in your answer.

Comment: wdym its in the paste bin

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies in your check function. The function does not return anything when it is supposed to return a boolean. You can do this with the `return` keyword.

```
    def checkReaction(reaction, user):
        return user != bot.user and (str(reaction.emoji) == ':x:' or str(reaction.emoji) == '✂' or str(reaction.emoji) == '')
```

Relevant documentation: [Bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)